# How to add code-snippet in documentation for C function?

Tags: c, documentation, vscode-snippets

**Hello there**

How I can add a code-snippet inside a documentation comment for a function

````
/*
** This is my special function
** it is used like this
** ```ft_printf("I am %d years too early for marriage", -1)```             <<-- like this?
*
int        ft_printf(const char *fmt, ...);
````

I am trying to become more communicative in the work i leave behind.
I did my best to find answers on the internet, just couldn't express my self well enough to get the answers i needed. hopefully a fellow human well help

Comment: Please document from the perspective that the reader will understand the language. Don't clutter code with compulsory ritual documentation (usually copy/paste and incorrect) that states the bleeding obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do it, so this is very subjective. One common way is to have a function banner for each function that describes the purpose of the function, its parameters, and the return value, e.g.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// @par    Function Name
///         printf_str
///
/// @brief  Log a str to the debug stream.
///
/// @param  const char *        String to be output
///
/// @retval int        0 for success, otherwise an error code
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int printf_str( const char * str )
```

You can then use tools like doxygen to generate documentation from your code.

Comment: Thank You for recommending Doxygen. Seems like a very cool tool